# Can't figure out unknown operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a problem I had on a test, and I completely don't understand where the answer is coming from.

If the operation Φ is defined for all X and Y by the equation XΦY=2Y/3X, then 4Φ(2Φ3)= ?

The answer given was 3/2, and the explanation is that the equation becomes 4Φ(18/12)=4Φ3=18/12=3/2.

It seems to me like the answer should be 4Φ(2Φ3)=4Φ((3x2)/2x3))=4Φ(6/6)=4Φ1=(2x1)/(3x4)=1/6.

Which wasn't even one of the multiple choice answers.
So I'm obviously completely misunderstanding the problem; some one please help.

Comment: Neither answer is correct, but yours is closer: you just slipped up at the end, where you should have $\frac{2\cdot1}{3\cdot4}=\frac16$.

Comment: When you write 2Y/3X, do you mean $(2Y)/(3X)$, or do you mean ${2Y\over3}X$?

Comment: Its (2Y)/(3X).  Is there a way to upload a screenshot to the website?  Then you can see it exactly as I do.

Comment: Greg, you have to earn a certain number of points before the software allows you to upload images. But if you're going to be here regularly, it will pay you to learn something about how to format mathematics on this website. There are links in the faq....

Answer (score 2):

If you defined $\Phi$ here as it was defined on the test, then your calculation of $2\Phi3$ is correct. Then you have a minor slip: $4\Phi 1=\frac{2\cdot 1}{3\cdot 4}$.

Comment: Thank you, my brother just pointed that error out to me as well.  But then it would seem as if the problem on the test is wrong.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the answer, if their definition of $\Phi$ is exactly what you wrote down, their calculation is wrong.